# How to create thunk in x64?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I've found nice [example how to create thunk for closure](https://gist.github.com/vidarh/259462#file-closures-thunks-c), but it's 32-bit version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct env {
  int x;
};

struct __attribute__((packed)) thunk {
  unsigned char push;
  struct env * env_addr;
  unsigned char call;
  signed long call_offset;
  unsigned char add_esp[3];
  unsigned char ret;
};

struct thunk default_thunk = {0x68, 0, 0xe8, 0, {0x83, 0xc4, 0x04}, 0xc3};

typedef void (* cfunc)();

struct thunk * make_thunk(struct env * env, void * code)
{
  struct thunk * thunk = (struct thunk *)mmap(0,sizeof(struct thunk), PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  *thunk = default_thunk;
  thunk->env_addr = env;
  thunk->call_offset = code - (void *)&thunk->add_esp[0]; // Pretty!                                                                               
  mprotect(thunk,sizeof(struct thunk), PROT_EXEC);
  return thunk;
}


void block(struct env * env) {
  env->x += 1;
  printf ("block: x is %d\n", env->x);
}

cfunc foo (int x)
{
  struct env * env = (struct env *)malloc(sizeof(struct env));
  env->x = x;

  printf ("x is %d\n",env->x);

  return (cfunc)make_thunk(env,(void *)&block);
}

int main() {
  cfunc c = foo(5);

  c();
  c();
}
```

How can I rewrite it for 64-bit version?

I'm using Linux x86_64. I've been able to cross-compile it with `gcc -m32`, which worked perfectly.

Comment: Thx, downvoter... please, elaborate what is wrong with the question?

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted but I would venture to guess down votes might be because you didn't seem to put effort into trying to create a 64 bit version and show what 64 bit code you have already tried. It comes across as a _gimme the code_ type of question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well, I put a lot of effort just to find this example. I've got very low knowledge about assembly at all, not about how to pack instructions into memory. I've also tried finding solution for this, but without luck. I know it's something like: push, call, pop, return instructions. However, to be able to write it on my own, I would have to study x64 specifications for at least month.

Comment: Missing from your question is what environment you are building in (compiler / OS). I venture to guess with the use of mmap you are probably using a *nIx variant (not Windows). Many C compilers for those platforms, but GCC would be a good guess. Your question should be more specific on these details.

Comment: You need to disassemble the code in `default_thunk` and then assemble a new 64-bit version. You'll need to make a new version of `struct thunk` accordingly. You'll also need to change the thunk code to use the 64-bit calling convention rather than 32-bit calling convention.

Comment: "To be able to write on my own, I would have to study x64 specifications for at least a month." In other words, "gimme the code". That's not what this Web site is for. (Also, if you know x86, then x64 can be learned in one day.)

Comment: And as an addendum to @RossRidge if the calling convention is 64bit ABI then the assembler code needs to pass the first parameter (address of environment) in register `%rdi`, do the call and then `ret`. All pointers will be 64 bit and not 32 so that has to be adjusted in the thunking struct.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't know x86, the lowest level of programming I know is LLVM assembly, but only little bit of it. But LLVM assembly is still textual code, that needs to be compiled to binary assembly, which differs a lot. Assembly is topic I haven't had/learned in school, yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below is designed to be used with GCC on Linux and should support 32 and 64 bit compilation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct env {
    int x;
};

#if __x86_64__
struct __attribute__((packed)) thunk {
    unsigned char mov[2];
    struct env * env_addr;
    unsigned char movrax[2];
    void (*call_address)();
    unsigned char jmp[2];
};

struct thunk default_thunk = {{0x48, 0xbf}, 0x0, {0x48, 0xb8}, 0x0, {0xff, 0xe0} };
#elif __i386__
struct __attribute__((packed)) thunk {
    unsigned char push;
    struct env * env_addr;
    unsigned char call;
    signed long call_offset;
    unsigned char add_esp[3];
    unsigned char ret;
};
struct thunk default_thunk = {0x68, 0, 0xe8, 0, {0x83, 0xc4, 0x04}, 0xc3};
#else
#error Architecture unsupported
#endif


typedef void (* cfunc)();

struct thunk * make_thunk(struct env * env, void * code)
{
    struct thunk * thunk = (struct thunk *)mmap(0,sizeof(struct thunk), 
                            PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *thunk = default_thunk;
#if __x86_64__
    thunk->env_addr = env;
    thunk->call_address = code; /* Pretty! */
#else
    thunk->env_addr = env;
    thunk->call_offset = code - (void *)&thunk->add_esp[0]; /* Pretty! */
#endif
    mprotect(thunk,sizeof(struct thunk), PROT_EXEC);
    return thunk;
}


void block(struct env * env) {
    env->x += 1;
    printf ("block: x is %d\n", env->x);
}

cfunc foo (int x)
{
    struct env * env = (struct env *)malloc(sizeof(struct env));
    env->x = x;

    printf ("x is %d\n",env->x);

    return (cfunc)make_thunk(env,(void *)&block);
}

int main() {
    cfunc c = foo(5);
    c();
    c();

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that the OS is using [System V 64bit ABI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706074221/www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (Which Linux uses) calling convention then the first parameter that will be passed to the function will be in register `%rdi`. Then we just have to `mov` the environment address (`env_addr`) to `%rdi` and then do a `call`. The call uses an indirect jump to an absolute location through `%rax`. So the instruction sequence looks like (at&t syntax):

```
mov    $env_addr, %rdi
movabs $call_pointer, %rax
jmpq  *%rax                   # Tail call instead of call/retq
```

Comment: @RossRidge : I finally got a chance to clean this up taking into account your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, and you're right. It's not an homework, this question goes much beyond scope of my lectures or any HW I've done so far. (even, now are still summer holidays in our country). In meantime I've done similar solution with LLVM IR and trampoline, which I'm gonna share on github after I do some cleanup to it.

Comment: For better branch prediction, you can choose dynamically between the `movabs` version and the direct call version based on whether the call target is within 2GB of the call source.

Comment: You should be able to tail-call with `jmp *%rax` instead of `call / ret`.